# When use auth.inMemoryAuthentication() or auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working with `Spring Security`

About configurations, I have seen through some sources the following two approaches:

**One**:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("someuser").password("somepassword").authorities("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER");
    //more as above
}
```

And

**Two**

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(User.withUsername("someuser").password("somepassword").authorities("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER").build());
    //more as above
    return inMemoryUserDetailsManager;
}
```

Until here the purpose or goal is create for development some users in-memory. Practically **both** *work*. Thus:

- When an option is mandatory over the other?

Answer (score 2):

Second variant is more generic and thus more flexible and registered using `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer`. Which accepts any UserDetailsProvider where you picked the In-memory standard implementation.

First one is more compact because `InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer` is standard.

But in the end the result is the same since `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder#apply` is called: it accepts three types: DAO (your 2nd), In-memory (your 1st) and JDBC Configurers.